# Azure API Management + Azure Function and managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to call an Azure function from an API Management instance by using Managed Identity.
I have set a System Managed Identity to my APIM instance.
I have granted the Contributor role to this identity on the Azure Function App.
I have also change the App Service Authentication to AD.

Now I'm trying to call the function from an API.

I have two issues:

1. First One: when I use the authentication-managed-identity policy to get a token, I got an error when I use the audience https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net. AD tells me that this app is not registered in the tenant
2. Second: If I retrieve a token for https://management.azure.com, I got a token but I received a 401 Unauthorized error from the Azure Function.

Maybe I'm just trying to get a token on the wrong audience, but unfortunately the audience of functions is not listed in the document (for service bus for example, there is a common URI to use, also for KeyVault, ...).

I think that I probably missed something in the picture...
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `authentication-managed-identity` policy to authenticate with a backend service using the managed identity of the API Management service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity

**EDIT**

1-In your APIM application on Azure AD,
grab the Application ID assigned for enterprise application.

2-Then go to Platform features in your Azure Function App, and click on Authentication / Authorization.

3-Select Azure Active Directory as the authentication provider, and the management mode "express".

4-Back to authentication-managed-identity policy, set the Application ID from step 1 as the resource.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done but as I said in my post, when I use the App URI ID of my Function, I can't get a token, it tells me that the App is not registered in the tenant (which is false because I can see it in the tenant).

Comment: It should be used Application ID and not Object ID

Comment: Based on this answer I created short post with instructions: https://kalcik.net/2020/04/15/use-managed-identity-in-azure-api-management-to-authenticate-with-an-azure-function/

Comment: This recent blog post might be helpful as well: https://mikaelsand.se/2021/09/secure-communication-with-apim-and-functions-using-managed-identity/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the url in apim required resource. If you're planning to use delegated flow. To check if the issue is with the url registration you can use the AppId instead. This will at least tell you if the token can be retrieved.